# Telegram webhook not found even though it exists

Tags: php, telegram, webhooks, telegram-bot

I can't figure out why the Telegram API says that the `webhook.php` doesn't exist even though I can access it using a browser.

Telegram API:

> {"ok":false,"error_code":404,"description":"Not Found"}

The link:

> https://api.telegram.org/56014xxxx:AAxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/setWebhook?url=https://hexah.net/Telegram/webhook.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end the issue was that the URL need to be encoded

> https://api.telegram.org/botxxxx:xxxx/setWebhook?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.hexah.net%2FTelegram%2Fwebhook.php

(Thanks who help me on the Telegram Bot Channel)

but I still don't understand why my old link was working fine without encoding...

Answer (score 4):

Please try this URL format instead:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot56014xxxx:AAxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/setWebhook?url=https://hexah.net/Telegram/webhook.php
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you incorrectly authorized your bot/application see https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#authorizing-your-bot